# How to set limits in y-axis in plotting 2-d graph in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

I have `x`-axis data and `y`-axis data.

```
x = [3;4;5;7;11;20;21;23;25;35;50]

y = [90;88;83;81;79;77;76;73;71;71;69]
```

I want to plot this graph. Now, I need two things:

1. `y`-axis should start from 50 and end at 100 with markers at an interval of 5.
2. On `x`-axis, I actually want to print `3*3`,`4*4`,`5*5`, and so on.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. y-axis should start from 50 and end at 100 with markers at an
   interval of 5.

   http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/individual-axis-control.html?searchHighlight=y%20axis%20ticks
2. on x-axis, i actually want to print 3*3,4*4,5*5, and so on.

   x1 = x .* x

   then plot x1

Comment: You wrongly interpreted the second one. I am trying to print (x*x) on output of graph. for eg. want to print 3*3 and not 9.

Comment: On the x-axis? Check the link in 1, and go to the section with title: **Setting Tick Mark Locations**, using XTickLabel.